# Deleting a binary from the bin folder that attempts to open at startup in Mac Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: macos, command-line, permission

There is a binary named 'Open' that resides in my `/usr/bin` folder that I cannot delete. I have tried `sudo rm open` and even tried `sudo su` and then `rm open` and it fails because I cannot override the permissions.

I have tried to use `chmod` and that does not work either. Perhaps I need to enable root and then try?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: hi - this is not a security related question, you probably need to ask in unix & linux or elsewhere. Having said that, you may want to check the attributes of the binary to see if the "immutable" flag is set. If it is, then you should remove it (look for *chflags* for mac) before you remove the binary itself

Comment: Do you have SIP on? It's sometimes used to keep even root from deleting certain files.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it?

Answer (score 3):

> There is a binary named 'Open' that resides in my usr/bin folder that I cannot delete.

#### You cannot and should not delete this file!

It’s a macOS utility that allows you to open files and folders with the registered application (or alternatively specify a different one) from the command line. For full details, see the [`open` man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/open/).

You cannot delete the file nor modify its permissions because its protected by the read only volume of the APFS container.  Even with root privileges, you won’t be able to delete it; disabling SIP will not have any effect either.

Even if you could, you’d be deleting a *valid* macOS binary.  This would likely be copied back to the `/usr/bin` directory on the next update.